# plot nonlinear regression conf intervals in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, non-linear-regression

Please help.
I have managed to fit a fairly decent nonlinear regression curve to my data using:

```
model2 <- nls(urine~a*(1-exp(-c*water)), data = eagle, start = list(a=550, c=0.00385))
```

and then I generate my plot using:

```
av <- seq(0,1200, 0.5)
bv <- predict (model2, data=eagle, list(water=av))
plot (urine~water, data = eagle)
lines (av,bv)
```

I want to draw on some dotted lines for upper and lower 95% confidence intervals.  I have managed to write code for my linear regression analyses but I am struggling with the current nonlinear regression.  The following code:

```
a <- predict (model2, newdata=data.frame(water=av), interval="confidence")
```

for linear regressions this gives me a dataframe with three columns for fit, lwr and upr.  With my nonlinear regression it just gives me a list of numbers which I cant do anything with.  Any suggestions?  Is there a simple way to get upper and confidence lines for a nonlinear regression?

Comment: se.fit isnt operating apparently.  Found lots of forums discussing the difficulties of fitting confidence intervals to non linear regressions in R.  After a whole day of searching and banging my head against the internet I finally found a very helpful formula.  Im not 100% sure how it works but it works so here it is for anyone else who needs to do this...

http://www.r-bloggers.com/predictnls-part-1-monte-carlo-simulation-confidence-intervals-for-nls-models/

Answer (score 1):

se.fit isnt operating apparently.  Found lots of forums discussing the difficulties of fitting confidence intervals to non linear regressions in R.  After a whole day of searching and banging my head against the internet I finally found a very helpful formula.  Im not 100% sure how it works but it works so here it is for anyone else who needs to do this...

http://www.r-bloggers.com/predictnls-part-1-monte-carlo-simulation-confidence-intervals-for-nls-models/

Once you have produced your table of statistics for your predicted values based on a sequence of x values, you can access the lwr and upr CI value data in columns 6 and 7 of the output and plot that way.